# IIS 8.5: Force all sites to use HTTPS

Tags: ssl, https, iis-8

Wanting to know if there is a way to force all sites in IIS 8.5 to HTTPS instead of HTTP without having to create rewrite rules for each site we deploy to the box.  We had one site get deployed to an internal server where the rules were not written in the config file and were just looking for a way to alleviate that miss in the future.

Comment: You can define HTTP to HTTPS redirection at server level in `applicationHost.config` for all sites.

Answer (score 0):

You can set this rule in applicationHost.config.

```
    <rewrite>
        <globalRules>
           <rule name="http to https" enabled="true">
            <match url="(.*)" />
            <conditions>
                <add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="^Off$" />
            </conditions>
            <action type="Rewrite" url="https://{HTTP_HOST}/{R:1}" />
          </rule>
        </globalRules>
    </rewrite>
```